# Hibernate criteria Restriction alters propertyname to first letter uppercase

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hibernate-annotations

I'm converting Hibernate hbm.xml files to hibernate annotations,
when I use the following code, I always get a
could not resolve property "**P**hone" (uppercase first letter) error

and I have no idea why hibernate changes "phone" to "Phone" ( phone is a field in Phone.class with a getter "getPhone")

```
  public List<Phone> findAllPhones(Orderergroup orderergroup,
      Suppliercategory suppliercategory) {
    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(Phone.class, "t")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("phone", orderergroup));
    if (suppliercategory != null && suppliercategory.getId() != null) {
      crit.add(Restrictions.eq("phone", suppliercategory));
    }
    return crit.list();
  }
```

In Phone.class supcat is mapped like this

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Suppliercategory.class, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SUPCAT_id", nullable = false)
private Suppliercategory        supcat;
```

The old .hbm.xml file contains

```
<many-to-one name="Supcat" class="Suppliercategory"
    not-null="true" unique-key="unique_phone">
    <column name="SUPCAT_id" />
</many-to-one>
```

Has anyone an idea what could be the cause of my problem?

I'm using hibernate 3.0, at the end I would like to use the newest version.

Comment: Did you try Phone.phone?  Why don't you change phone to something more meaningful?

Comment: yes, unfortunately didn't work, "Phone" is just an example, you can replace it with whatever you want ;)

Comment: What is phone type?  Show the complete Phone class, Orderergroup and Suppliercategory